# errors using colfilt to speed up computation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to perform a sliding neighborhood operation using colfilt. 
I am basically trying to run a 2X2 window on an image while running some functions:

```
f = @(x,y) (func(diff(x:x+1,y:y+1),s(x:x+1,y:y+1)));
e = colfilt(img, [2 2], 'silding', f);
```

where diff and s are same size as the img (responses calculated in various ways).
func is a function that performs some computations on diff and s.

I keep getting this error:

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in colfilt (line 133)
    if all(block>=size(a)), % Process the whole matrix at once.

Error in create_e (line 14)
e = colfilt(img, [2 2], 'silding', f);
```

any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: My thoughts: `block` and `a` are not of the same size. Type `edit colfilt` to open the source code and find out what those to are.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wanting to use a different function, `nlfilter`, or you need to adapt your function, because it seems you're assuming the input of your function is a 2-by-2 array.

`colfilt` reshapes each block into a nElementsInBlock-by-1 array and arranges them in a nElementsInBlock-by-nBlocks array, so that you can calculate the function (e.g. kurtosis) in a single step.

`nlfilter` applies a function on a sliding window, passing each block as a n-by-m array to a user-defined function.